# Python: For loops breaking issue

Tags: for-loop, conditional-statements, break

I'm using a for loop, and inside the for loop are two if-statements that are both being checked for each iteration of the for loop. My issue is that once one of the if-statements = True, then I want the True if-statement to stop being checked, and only check the second if-statement. Or vice versa.

```
print("Guess the numbers it is! Your goal is to guess a two digit number from 00-99. The two digits may be the same.")
numGuessesN = int(input("How many guesses would you like? (2, 3, or 4) "))

for numGuessesN in range (firstGuess, numGuessesN + 1) :
    print("Guess number", numGuessesN)
    userGuessN = int(input("What is your guess? "))



    if (userGuessN == randomNum1) :
        print("You've guessed the first number!") 
        break
    else :
        print("The first number is not", userGuessN)

    if (userGuessN == randomNum2) :
        print("You've guessed the second number!")
        break
    else :
        print("The second number is not", userGuessN)
```

I know the breaks in the if-statements will completely exit the for loop, and that's not what I want. But somehow I need the for loop to "break" for only each individual statement if it turns out the statement is true, and keep checking the remaining statement until it's true, or the loop runs out of iterations.

Thanks guys! I'm new to all of this, so I'm sorry if I'm not really clear haha.

Answer (score 0):

either you use nested if-statements, or (in case you have a lot, so you would have a lot of repeated code) you set a variable

```
first_wrong=False
if bla:
    pass
else:
    first_wrong=True

if bla2 and not first_wrong:
    pass
if bla3 and not first_wrong:
    pass
```